# Objective-C library internally displays Invalid URL scheme

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a library that I would like to use, but I am getting the error `Invalid URL scheme for background downloads: (null). Valid schemes are http or https`. Is there a way I can debug which URL is used that causes this error?

I do not have access to the source code of this library.

Is there a symbolic breakpoint that I can set when this error is returned from `NSURLSession`?

Or a way I can view parameters in the debugger when I am browsing the call stack?

Comment: @Close voter: This is not a question about "why is this NSURLSession not working?", this is a question about debugging the app, this is simply an example use case I am giving (closed source library, trying to figure out parameters). If you have a remark about my question, please put it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know about symbolic breakpoints, sure. It'll be one of the `NSURLSession` methods related to starting download tasks:

```
downloadTaskWithURL:completionHandler:
downloadTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:
```

One of those almost certainly will have to be called eventually.

Regarding viewing the parameters in the debugger, you'll want to consult the glorious chart by Clark Cox: [Inspecting Obj-C parameters in gdb](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/). It quickly covers how parameters are passed on each platform.

Comment: I am debugging on an iPhone 6S, which, to my knowledge, uses arm. I try to do `po $r0`, but I am getting `error: use of undeclared identifier '$r0'`. However, `po *(id*)($sp)` returns`<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x17009d8d0>` Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, I had to replace all `r`s with `x`s, so it becomes `po $x0`

Comment: yeah… I ran into that before in lldb. But I think it actually will help you out with $arg1 (etc) aliases.